# How to change the minSdk version in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get a basic hello world program running on my phone, however Android Studio keeps on reverting to minSDK level 20, when I specified 14. Here is the process I am using:

-Start Android Studio 0.8.2
-Select New Project
-Select Minimum SDK as API 14: Android 4.0
-Select Blank Activity
-The new project is now open. My android device, running 4.4.2 API 19 is plugged in.
-Select "Run app"
-The "Choose Device" dialog opens, shows my android device, but shows compatibility as `No, minSdk(API 20, L preview)!= deviceSdk(API19)`

The following is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.victor.myapplications"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Changing 'compileSdkVersion' to 14 results in an error, "failed to find target android-14".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The "L" Developer Preview is a special snowflake that breaks all the normal rules for version management. :-(

Unless you are an experienced Android developer specifically testing on "L", change `compileSdkVersion` to something like `19` (note: may require you to download the SDK Platform for API Level 19 from the SDK Manager) and change `targetSdkVersion` to `19`.

> Changing 'compileSdkVersion' to 14 results in an error, "failed to find target android-14".

You need to download the API Level 14 "SDK Platform" in the SDK Manager.

Comment: One can put compileSdkVersion 20 and targetSdkVersion 20 and not have to download anything additional and have it work on his API 19 device as well.

Comment: @svenoaks: Well, you don't know whether the OP has the SDK Platform for API Level 20 installed. There's a chance that it is installed, but it is not guaranteed. `targetSdkVersion` does not depend upon things being downloaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.victor.myapplications"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

If the target keep giving to you this problem try putting a lower version like CommonsWare said !