# Android Studio / Eclipse import error

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-studio, error-handling

I am here with a simple problem. I have created a game project in one of the game builders (BuildBox) and now, when I try to import and convert it into an .apk, I get this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1] C:\Users\Rob.android\build-cache\8f9b56554d0082e5d885287503f760ae18c8f99a\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

The problem is that I am an absolute newbie with Android Studio and I have no idea how could I update the "minSdkVersion" from 11 to 14.

I will appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details. FI you search in google you will find tons of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the minSdk version in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222183/how-to-change-the-minsdk-version-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your build.gradle file of app module in your application, and look for "minSdkVersion" parameter in defaultConfig block.
Just change it to your suitable version.